# Assign units of an object to groups without assigning to units of the same object to a group

Tags: r, algorithm

I try to assign elements randomly to groups, but it seems that it's either surprisingly complicated or I am missing the obvious solution.

Remark: My attempt is written in R but I am happy about every comprehensible answer in any language.

**Input Data:**

A vector *o* containing the available units of an object where from each object up to *p-1* units might be available. Example for *o*: (0, 1, 5, 8, p-1, ...)

Furthermore there is a vector *g* containing available spots in groups. Each group can take either *p* or *p + 1* units. Example for *g*: (p, p + 1, p, p, p + 1, ...)

The following restriction applies to the input data:

- All groups have just enough spots for all available objects sum(o) == sum(g)

**Expected Output**

The available objects should be randomly distributed to the groups, but no group can hold more than one unit of each object. The order in which units are assigned to a group is not relevant.

**Example**

Example 1:

```
elements <- c(2, 1)
group_sizes <- c(1, 2)
```

The only possible solution is

```
(1), (1, 2)
```

Explanation: 1 Unit of the first object in the first group, the groups contains one unit of both objects

Example 2:

```
elements <- c(2,1,1)
group_sizes <- c(1, 2, 1)
```

Possible solutions:

```
(1), (1, 2), (3)
(1), (1, 3), (2)
(1), (2, 3), (1)
(2), (1, 3), (1)
(3), (1, 2), (1)
```

**I am looking for an algorithm returning for an given input one of the possible distributions. All distributions should have an equal chance to be returned.**

** My unsuccessful approach**

I thought about assigning per iteration one unit to each group. Units cannot be assigned to groups already containing a unit of the same object. Distribution order is starting with the most common object to least common object and then restarting with the most common object.

```
# Group sizes
group_sizes <- c(8,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,8)
# Available units of objects (already sorted by size)
object_units <- c(8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,6)

# Generate a distributions order
dist_order <- numeric(0)

while(max(object_units) > 0){
  dist_order <- c(dist_order, which(object_units > 0))
  object_units <- object_units - 1 
}


n_groups <- length(group_sizes)

result <- matrix(numeric(0), ncol = n_groups, nrow = min(group_sizes))

set.seed(1)

# distribute batch with
for(i in 1:min(group_sizes)){
  # get the objects of which units are distributed in this batch
  ind <- (i - 1) * n_groups + 1
  current <- v[ind:(ind +  n_groups - 1)]
  # beginning with the batch all groups can be distributed
  avail_groups <- 1: n_groups

  #iterate over groups an select object to assign to group
  for (j in 1:n_groups) {
    # current object can only be assigned to where it has not been assigned yet
    free <- which(colSums(result == current[j], na.rm = TRUE) == 0)
    # current object can only be assigned to where no other object has been assigned to in this batch
    current_avail_groups <- intersect(avail_groups, free)

    # select from remaining groups on to assign the assign the object
    if(length(current_avail_groups) == 1){
      selected_group <- current_avail_groups
    } else {
      selected_group <- sample(current_avail_groups, size = 1)
    }
    # store assignment in result matrix
    result[i, selected_group] <- current[j]
    # remove group from available groups for this iteration
    avail_groups <- avail_groups[selected_group != avail_groups]
  }

}
```

This is no valid algorithm as at it is possible that at some point for some object all groups either already contain a unit of the object or received already a unit of another object within this iteration.

Comment: These wouldn't be permutations?

Comment: I would say yes, but not all permutations are valid I guess?

Comment: So, permute then assess through a truth tree that identifies valid vs invalid from your result matrix. I'm a little puzzled by the 3 in example 2, which I understand is there for readability. So, unique. If all elements were 0, n = 10, there would have to be 10 groups, for uniqueness. `which(unique(c(0,0,0,0,0,0)) == FALSE)
[1] 1
> length(c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
[1] 6`, sorry, just trying to reduce to simplest cases, unsuccessfully. But p-1.